# Equipotential Lines plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, physics

I have these 3 DataFrames, each one with points of an equipotencial line. The tensions are v1, v2 and v3. I need to plot the equipotential lines, in the same graph. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
d1={'X': [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2],
    'Y': [0.0, 1.9, 2.9, -1.0, -2.0]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(d1, columns=['X', 'Y'])
v1 = 3.93


d2={'X': [-2.0, -2.3, -2.4, -2.3, -2.5],
    'Y': [0.0, 2.0, 2.9, -2.0, -3.0]}
df2=pd.DataFrame(d2, columns=['X', 'Y'])
v2 = 4,98


d3={'X': [2.0, 2.3, 3.1, 2.3, 3.1],
    'Y': [0.0, 2.0, 3.9, -2.0, -4.0]}
df3=pd.DataFrame(d3, columns=['X', 'Y'])
v3 = 3.07
```

Comment: I have no idea what equipotencial line or tensions are but the matplotlib library is what most python graphing libraries are built on. What values do you want to plot and I can show you.

Comment: Ty, but I think you need the physics for this one. I already plotted a scatter plot of those points, but the lines connecting them are what really matters to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot lines with matplotlib's `plt.plot()`. For the polygons to be closed, the first point should be appended again at the end. Note that the example data don't form nice polygons. Optionally the polygons can be colored with `plt.fill()`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'X': [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2], 'Y': [0.0, 1.9, 2.9, -1.0, -2.0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1, columns=['X', 'Y'])
v1 = 3.93

d2 = {'X': [-2.0, -2.3, -2.4, -2.3, -2.5], 'Y': [0.0, 2.0, 2.9, -2.0, -3.0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns=['X', 'Y'])
v2 = 4, 98

d3 = {'X': [2.0, 2.3, 3.1, 2.3, 3.1], 'Y': [0.0, 2.0, 3.9, -2.0, -4.0]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(d3, columns=['X', 'Y'])
v3 = 3.07

for df, v, color in zip([df1, df2, df3], [v1, v2, v3], ['dodgerblue', 'crimson', 'limegreen']):
    x = np.append(df['X'], df['X'][0])
    y = np.append(df['Y'], df['Y'][0])
    plt.plot(x, y, color=color, label=f'v={v}')
    plt.fill(x, y, color=color, alpha=0.3)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]